# Encontrar PC en diferente sub red usando c#

Tags: c#, networking

Primero, perdonen si el titulo no es muy sugerente, debido a que no se que es lo que realmente necesito.

Este es mi escenario, para que entiendan mi duda.
Actualmente, como diversion (seria), me encuentro desarrollando un Launcher para un juego aun muy popular en mi red: Call Of Duty Modern Warfare 3. Y todo va bien mientras el servidor esta corriendo en una IP en mi subred. Pero, otros usuarios de diferentes subredes no pueden ver la instancia del servidor levantado. Para ello tienen que recurrir a una aplicacion llamada [BattleLAN.exe](http://lancraft.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-use-battlelan.html)

Simplemente añadiendo la IP del servidor del juego, pueden ver la partida en su cliente de juego.
Mi duda reside en como lograr lo mismo que hace esta aplicacion.
He encontrado articulos sobre [ARP](https://www.ionos.es/digitalguide/servidores/know-how/arp-resolucion-de-direcciones-en-la-red/) pero no se si dirigirme por esa via porque no se que estoy buscando. Tambien lei algunos articulos sobre VPN, pero estas necesitan autenticacion y BattleLAN no lo requiere, asi que esa via no debe ser. Como no tengo experiencia suficiente en NetworkProgramming no se que conjunto de tecnologias es necesario para llevar a dicha tarea. Alguien pudiera orientarme?
Evidentemente intento desarrollar esto en c#.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Probablemente lo que esté haciendo BattleLAN es agregar una ruta desde la pc donde está el cliente al servidor donde estás corriendo el juego (Le dice por cuál interface de red le tiene que enviar los paquetes para que lleguen a la correspondiente subred subred). Fijate http://www.itgeared.com/articles/1129-using-windows-route-command/

Comment: Bueno parece ser bastante prometedor. Voy a leerlo con calma y hacer los experimentos pertinentes. Gracias @Juan

Comment: Bueno fui con mi calma probando algunas cosas y resulta que la tabla de rutas antes y despues de usar BattleLan es la misma. No varia. Alguna otra sugerencia? Probe tambien observando la tabla de ARP y tampoco varia con el BattleLan